# Python - Ciphertext length must be equal to key size - different string length after passing it to server

Tags: python, string, cryptography

I have a problem with decoding the encrypted message after passing it from client to the server. I am using [Cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/). I am encoding the message on the client side using the script below:

```
encMessage = public_key.encrypt(message, padding.OAEP(mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA1()), algorithm=hashes.SHA1(),label=None))
```

After this encoding the *len()* function on the client side tells me properly that the *encMessage* is 256 long. Also the *type()* function tells me that *encMessage* is *'str'*. The *encMessage* when printed looks something like this:

> I\xf0gr\xf5\xf8\xf2F\xde\xc7\xe4\x91\xa1F3\xc1\x05\x06\xd7Y:\xc9\xcf\xed'\xf49\xd5\x99Z\xed\x93\xba8\xdd\x0b\xe3?

However, when I pass this *encMessage* to the server using *rest_framework* then, after using the code below on the server side:

```
message = private_key.decrypt(encMessage,padding.OAEP(mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA1()), algorithm=hashes.SHA1(),label=None))
```

I get the error: "Ciphertext length must be equal to key size". I checked this and now the *len()* function on the server side used on *encMessage* gives me not 256 but something smaller. Also the *type()* function shows *'unicode'*.

I assume that there is something wrong with *encMessage* conversion during data sending from client to server but I have no idea what to do with it.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

**EDIT:**

Answering the comment about showing how I communicate with the server and send the data - this is what I do:

```
data = {'message': $scope.message};
loginApi.getMessageEncrypted(data)
    .success(
        function(dataEncrypted) {
            loginApi.checkMessage(dataEncrypted['encMessage'])
                .success(
                    function(dataDecrypted) {
                        $log.log('Server responded properly');
                    })
                .error(
                    function(errorInfo, status) {
                        $log.info('Server user data answer error.')
                    });
        })
    .error(
        function(errorInfo, status) {
            $log.info('Client encryption error.')
        });
```

Explanation:

After clicking some button on the website angular's *getMessageEncrypted* function sends *message* in *data* variable using *post* to *django REST framework* APIview and then serializer object which are written in python on the client side. In serializer the message is encrypted using:

```
encMessage = public_key.encrypt(message, padding.OAEP(mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA1()), algorithm=hashes.SHA1(),label=None))
dataEncrypted = {'encMessage': encMessage};
return dataEncrypted
```

and sent back to angular using *dataEncrypted* dictionary-like variable. Then this message is sent with angular's *checkMessage* function (also with *post*) to the *django REST framework* APIview and then serializer object on the server side. In server's serializer the message is decrypted using:

```
message = private_key.decrypt(encMessage,padding.OAEP(mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA1()), algorithm=hashes.SHA1(),label=None))
```

and similarly sent back to angular in *dataDecrypted* dictionary-like variable. However, this never happens because in the decryption line I get *Ciphertext length must be equal to key size* error.

I think that there is some change of the message coding (like utf-8, unicode or something) on the border of client-angular when encrypted message is sent to angular from python function on the client side or on the border of angular-server when encrypted message is sent from angular to python APIview on the server side.

I am really sorry for probably lack of "naming" experience. I am not really into proper nomenclature.

**SOLUTION**

User [mata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1350899/mata) answered my question. What I had to do was to encode encrypted message with *base64* before returning it to angular and sending it to server api. Then on the server side I had to decode it from *base64* and then decode the message. Thank you again!

Comment: Debugging is part of writing code, add the results of your debugging efforts to the question, not: "something like". Check the length being sent/received. examine the communications with something like Charles Proxy. Understand that encrypted anything is binary data, not a character string, as such it will contain bytes that have no display character, thus best displayed as hexadecimal.

Comment: Thank you for a comment. This "something like" part was added to the question just to visualize the overall form of the encoded message when it is printed with python print function. I wasn't sure if it is even important. I think that the most important debugging result is already mentioned: the length of the encrypted message in client and in server is 256 and e.g. 243, respectively. Also, the result of the type() function is 'str' and 'unicode', respectively. However, Your notice about binary data and hexadecimal representation is interesting - I am going to check it. Thank you.

Comment: This seems like an issue with your data transmission and not with the encryption itself. The problem only came to light because the decryption procedure expected something different, but this is a valid expectation. If you don't find the issue yourself, please add the missing code which shows how the data is transmitted and received.

Comment: Yes - I think we need to see the code that is responsible for transmission to help you debug the problem. Please paste!

Comment: Dear mata... Guess who is awesome? You are awesome! Thank you a lot! The key word: "base64". That is what I was looking for! Thank you again!

Comment: In that case I'll post it as an answer so you can accept it. Glad it works :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your encrypted message is a binary blob of data, and you seem to treat it as string in javascript, but javascript strings are not made for binary data, and when the transport format is json it gets even more complicated.

The standard approach would be to base64 encode the encrypted message before sending and decode it when it's received.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when working with encryption on django project. In order to solve the error check bellow points

- Make sure to encode using base64 before sending data to db and on retrieving data decode it
- User Binary key for storing this field in database and not Character based field
- This seems silly but also make sure that you are using right pair of keys for encryption and decryption, and reading correct key for encryption and decryption. It is also good idea to check encryption is working properly by making small program so in case if there is little error in encryption it will not bother you in you project. Beacause it is comparatively hard to solve the same error in project. Because of complexity of project.

Answer (score 0):

User mata(1st answer) works for me too. I spoiled one whole day for this.
In python
import base64

### data = base64.b64encode(cipher_text)
// send it over network

On receiving end

import base64

rec_data = base64.b64decode(received_data)